# How to change values of textboxes inside td and storing changed values in db using Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, laravel

I have some values inside a td in textboxes.what i want to do is when i changed(ng-blur) text box value it should affect other values at the same time and changed values should send to the controller for db operations. how can i do this?

HTML

```
<td><input type="text" id="outUser" name="outUser" ng-model="dailyAttendance.outUser"  ng-init="dailyAttendance.outUser | formatTime" ng-blur="dailyAttendances.sendData(dailyAttendance.outUser)"></td>
<td>{{ dailyAttendance.lateUser | formatTime}}</td>
<td>{{ dailyAttendance.workedUser | formatTime}}</td>
<td>{{ dailyAttendance.OTUser | formatTime}}</td>
```

angular js

```
sendData(){
    this.success = false;
    this.submitted = true;
    if(this.$scope.DailyAttendanceForm.$valid) {
        this.errors = {};
        var that = this;

        this.spinnerBar.show(); // hide spinner bar
        this.$http.post(this.urls.BASE + '/outTime', this.entity)

        .success(
        function (response) {
            that.success = true;
            that.message = response.data;
            that.spinnerBar.hide(); // hide spinner bar
        })

        .error(
        function (status) {
            that.spinnerBar.hide(); // hide spinner bar
            var i=0;                          
        });
    }
    else{
        this.success = false;
    }
}
```

as a exmaple when i changed the 'outUser' value it needs to show same value on  lateUser and  workedUser fields

Comment: Or you may place a button, and call the dailyAttendances.sendData(dailyAttendance.outUser) function from it by markign it with ng-click directive. This will update the data only when you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

After sending your request to the DB and receving a response you should attach the attributs (lateUser,workedUser, .. ) in your controller and assign new values

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="outUser" name="outUser" ng-model="outUser" ng-blur="sendData()"></td>
      <td>{{lateUser}}</td>
      <td>{{workedUser}}</td>
      <td>{{OTUser}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.sendData = function(){

        /**
            do same job
    **/

    /**
      attach attributes to the current scope and assign new values
    **/
      $scope.lateUser = $scope.outUser + "lateUser"
    $scope.workedUser = $scope.outUser + "workedUser"
    $scope.OTUser = $scope.outUser + "OTUser"
}

});
```

[Full exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/hamedit4pme/uwcnh9c6/)